# Getting language issue while publish my blog url in linkedin page

Tags: wordpress, linkedin-api

I am getting issue when I paste my blog url in my linked in account page.I am getting the language issue there, If I paste another site's blog url to publish a new post.It publish post in English but Its not working with my site's blog as it convert into franch automatically when I paste my url.

Please let me know what is possibilities I can try to make it working?

Thanks,

Gaurav